# RxJava's retryWhen operator

Tags: android, rx-java2, retrywhen

I'm trying to understand retryWhen operator in depth and I have some code as below.

```
    Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen { throwable ->
                Log.d("Debug", "retryWhen proceed...")
                throw Exception("There is a exception")
            }
            .subscribe(
                    { item ->
                        Log.d("Debug", "success : $item")
                    },
                    { throwable ->
                        Log.d("Debug", "error : ${throwable.message}")
                    },
                    {
                        Log.d("Debug", "complete")
                    }
            )
```

And the result is shwon as below.

> Debug: retryWhen proceed...
>
> Debug: error : There is a exception

The question is that when retryWhen operator is triggered?

I assume retryWhen operator will be triggered only when there is a exception occurs.

But the result is not what I thought obviously,

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retryWhen { errors -> ... }` take an `Observable<Throwable>` and should return an `Observable` that return anything for *retrying* or an error for *stop retrying*.

One example could be:

```
.retryWhen(attempts -> {
  return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {
    System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
    return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  });
})
```

(taken from http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html)
This code will delay each retry.

By the way, throwing an exception is not the thing to do in this method.

**Documentation:**
* [Great blog article](https://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) that explained the `retryWhen`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my major question is that 
Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) do not emit any error to my observer, so I assume retryWhen operator would not be triiger. But thre behavior show me that retryWhen operator has be triggered.
How did this happened ?

Comment: The lambda [executes before](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/flowable/FlowableRetryWhen.java#L45) any subscription to `just` and you just crash the lambda. Do not crash the lambda.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you for you for your reply! After studying source code I totally understand what's going on!